# Scalaz for function code simplification

Tags: scala, scalaz

I wrote a Fibonacci function on `Scalaz` using bing operations. Here is my code:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

def fib(i: Int): Option[Int] = i match {
  case 0 => 0.some
  case 1 => 1.some
  case x if x > 1 =>
    fib(i - 1) >>= {
      a => fib(i - 2) >>= {
        b => (a + b).some
      }
    }
  case _ => None
}
```

Is it possible to simplify it? I don't like the stuff like this `a => fib(i - 2) >>= ...`.

Comment: how about do-notation (for-comprehension)?

Comment: `lazy val fib: Stream[Int] = 0 #:: fib.scan(1)(_+_)`

Comment: @jwhj as I understand, the point here was to process an error for negative numbers and discover scalaz-features

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks simpler, but without Scalaz:

```
def fib(i: Int): Option[Int] = i match {
  case 0 => 0.some //Ok, a little bit of Scalaz's syntax sugar
  case 1 => 1.some
  case x if x > 1 => for {
    a <- fib(i - 1)
    b <- fib(i - 2)
  } yield a + b
  case _ => None
}
```

Basically it's Haskell's do-notation, here you can see `<-` as a more convenient version of `>>=` (bind). Practically it expands to `flatMap` by compiler.

Scalaz can help when you need to do it for more complicated types (let's imagine you want to make it async/effectful, but still ordered) - you can use monadic transformers then. Here is the explanation from cats documentation (pretty much similar to scalaz, but much much clearer): http://typelevel.org/cats/tut/optiont.html.

When things get even more complicated (let's say you need to manage effectful computation for `Future` or `Task` along with error processing), it might help to use advanced transformers, like: https://github.com/djspiewak/emm

P.S. Do we need it all for Fibonacci? Probably not, but we can still imagine an external service for "minus" and "plus", so in that case Scalaz/Cats will help.

```
def minus(a: Int, b: Int): Task[Int] = Task.delay(a - b)
def plus(a: Int, b: Int): Task[Int] = Task.delay(a + b)
def fib(i: Int): Task[Option[Int]] = {...}
```

Which scalaz/cats can simplify (at least binding itself :) ) to:

```
def minus(a: Int, b: Int): OptionT[Task, String] = OptionT(Task.delay(Some(a - b)))
def plus(a: Int, b: Int): OptionT[Task, String] = OptionT(Task.delay(Some(a - b)))
```

and then to:

```
def minus(a: Int, b: Int): OptionT[Task, String] = OptionT.liftF(Task.delay(a - b))
def plus(a: Int, b: Int): OptionT[Task, String] = OptionT.liftF(Task.delay(a - b))

def fib(i: Int): OptionT[Task, String] = i match {
  case 0 => OptionT.pure(0)//OptionT.fromOption(0.some)
  case 1 => OptionT.pure(1)//OptionT.fromOption(1.some)
  case x if x > 1 => for {
    a <- fib(minus(i, 1))
    b <- fib(minus(i, 2))
    sum <- plus(a, b)
  } yield sum
  case _ => None
}
```

Example with error processing (scalaz/fs2 `Task` basically encapsulates them, but let's say you want precise types instead of `Throwable`)

```
type ServiceError = Throwable //use Xor.catchNonFatal to catch errors from external service
def minus(a: Int, b: Int): Task[Xor[ServiceError, Int]] = Task.delay((a - b).right)
def plus(a: Int, b: Int): Task[Xor[ServiceError, Int]] = Task.delay((a + b).right)
def fib(i: Int): Task[Option[Xor[ServiceError, Int]]] = {...}
```

Emm will simplify it to:

```
type ServiceError = Throwable //use Xor.catchNonFatal to catch errors from external service

//Note: you need kind-projector for that syntax: https://github.com/non/kind-projector
type E = Task |: (ServiceError \/ ?) |: Option |: Base 

def minus(a: Int, b: Int): Emm[E, Int] = ...
def plus(a: Int, b: Int): Emm[E, Int] = ...
def fib(i: Int): Emm[E, Int] = {...}
```

You can try complete those examples as an exercise.

P.S.2

You can also simplify pattern matching:

```
def fib(i: Int): Option[Int] = i match {
  case x if x < 0 => None //explicit validation comes first
  case x if x > 1 => for {
    a <- fib(i - 1)
    b <- fib(i - 2)
  } yield a + b
  case x => x.some
}
```

You can try to do validation with `Xor`/`\/` as an exercise: http://typelevel.org/cats/tut/xor.html

P.S.3 Note that all of your implementation is not stack-safe (no tailrec optimization), so you might need Trampoline to compensate (depending on your real task, as fibonacci are implemented a lot easier in stack-safe way, but without error on negative number, you can basically throw an exception or return 0):

http://blog.richdougherty.com/2009/04/tail-calls-tailrec-and-trampolines.html

Scalaz: http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Stackless+Scala+with+Free+Monads.html

In cats trampoline is just `Free[Function0, A]`:
        https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/free/src/main/scala/cats/free/Trampoline.scala

Talking about `Task`, it is actually trampolined inside, so it's safe to use it for such computations - so monadic transformers (`OptionT[Task, Int]`) are coming in hand here.

Answer (score 1):

To complement *dk14*'s answer :

Because `fib(i - 2)` doesn't depend on `fib(i - 1)`, we don't actually need `>>=` / `bind` / `flatMap`, we can do this with `Applicative`.

Your nested `>>=`'s (or the equivalent for comprehension) can be replaced by :

```
Apply[Option].apply2(fib(i - 1), fib(i - 2))(_ + _)
```

Or even simpler using the applicative builder syntax :

```
(fib(i - 1) |@| fib(i - 2))(_ + _)
```

Comment: +1, I'd also add that in my case (for imaginary external service) calculations are not just pseudo-dependent, but also sequential, which isn't good. Using just only parallel operator like `|@|` wouldn't help (except if it's a regular `Future`), but something like `Task.start(fib(i - 1) |@| Task.start(fib(i-2))` (which starts both computations asynchronously) would do the job.

Comment: Btw, for a simple case like `Option`, monoid might be even easier: `List(fib(i - 1), fib(i - 2)).suml`. `|+|` (and whatever `suml` is using inside) is a parallel operator as well, but also commutative.